# Android camera error

Tags: cyanogenmod, camera, samsung

I used to have TouchWiz 4.1.2 on my Samsung Galaxy Express, and now I have CyanogenMod 10.1.

The stock CM camera has this weird behaviour of - for lack of a better explanation - not letting go of the camera once opened.

The app works on the first launch, then reports that it can't connect to the camera on subsequent launches.
Other camera apps, like Retrica and Camera360, work flawlessly.

I'm guessing that the problem lies in the proprietary camera libraries, but they come from an official TouchWiz 4.2.2 build for a similar device - actually, a better term would be a successor, since the device is labeled Galaxy Express 2.

Logcat gives me this:

```
E/QualcommCamera(  277): Qint android::get_camera_info(int, camera_info*): E
E/QualcommCamera(  277): Qint android::get_camera_info(int, camera_info*): E
V/CameraHolder(15689): open camera 0
W/CameraService(  277): CameraService::connect X (pid 15689) rejected (existing client).
E/CameraHolder(15689): fail to connect Camera
E/CameraHolder(15689): java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail to connect to camera service
E/CameraHolder(15689):  at android.hardware.Camera.native_setup(Native Method)
E/CameraHolder(15689):  at android.hardware.Camera.<init>(Camera.java:340)
E/CameraHolder(15689):  at android.hardware.Camera.open(Camera.java:302)
E/CameraHolder(15689):  at com.android.camera.CameraManager.cameraOpen(CameraManager.java:291)
E/CameraHolder(15689):  at com.android.camera.CameraHolder.open(CameraHolder.java:210)
E/CameraHolder(15689):  at com.android.camera.Util.openCamera(Util.java:545)
E/CameraHolder(15689):  at com.android.camera.PhotoModule$CameraStartUpThread.run(PhotoModule.java:347)
V/StateManager(15689): startState class com.android.gallery3d.app.PhotoPage
E/mm-libcamera2(  277): mm_camera_poll_fn: preview polling error!! err = 0
E/QCameraHWI(  277): processEvent: type :0 E
I/QCameraHWI(  277): processChannelEvent: E
```

What is the problem, and how exactly can I solve it?

Comment: Probably this can only be fixed by fixing the bug in the Cyanogenmod source and building a new ROM. You might want to check to see if there is a newer version.

Comment: @DanHulme Actually my device does not have official support. So the libs aren't broken?

Comment: This is what we call a system integration error, which just means that the parts are put together wrong. It'll need some investigation to find exactly which component needs to change to fix it.

Comment: @DanHulme Thank you very much, I'll suggest this to my device maintainer.

Comment: Do you have a working solution to release the camera properly?